# Where can I find answers to Steve Tadelis An Introduction to Game Theory answers for chapters after the 8th one?

Tags: reference-request

I am doing exercises in the book Steve Tadelis An Introduction to Game Theory. I have answers to the even questions from chapters 1 to 8. But I would like to check the other remaining chapters' answers. I thought I could ask here as people here may know.

> Where can I find answers to Steve Tadelis An Introduction to Game Theory  answers for chapters after the 8th one?